# Starting Position of NSSplitView divider

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, nsview, nssplitview

How can I set the start position of a NSSplitView?

The closest thing I've found that looks like it would work is setPosition

```
//Set splitView position.
[splitView setPosition:330 ofDividerAtIndex:0];
```

This doesn't seem to do anything though, my splitview still starts with the divider in the center.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that is the center?  If splitView is correctly hooked up to your split view, that code should work.  You should probably log [splitView minPossiblePositionOfDividerAtIndex:0] and [splitView maxPossiblePositionOfDividerAtIndex:0] before trying to set the position of the divider so you know the possible values.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the center. My min value is 0 and my max value is 999.

Comment: I don't know what to say -- it worked fine for me. I wonder if it has anything to do with constraints settings?  I just dragged out a split view, added a few buttons and text fields to each side (so there would be something to see) and added that one line of code.

Comment: It seems the issue lies elsewhere, I have a setting that allows a user to choose their default view- if I set the view with the splitView as the default one then the split is in the center. If I set another view as the main one and click into the view with the splitView everything works fine. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: That seems odd, but I can't really tell without seeing the code.

Comment: You have to set the position of the divider after the view loads. A great place is the `- (void)viewWillAppear` method of its associated controller. I believe this relates to the fact that the `setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:` method interacts with the delegate in order to take into account imposed constraints and the split view's relationship with it's subviews. Remember that a divider is a subview of the split view itself.

Answer (score 5):

You don't set the position of the divider, you set the sizes of your NSSplitView's subviews. The divider is then repositioned automatically.

This is how I positioned my divider and subview size (in swift):

```
let subview: NSView = mySplitView.subviews[1] as NSView
subview.setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(subview.frame.size.width, 100))
```

Answer (score 4):

In the view's class housing the split view

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.mySplitView.setPosition(120, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
}
```

or wherever you want it to start.

Answer (score 3):

`NSSplitView` needs initial non-sized bounds to make them layout correctly.
If your view has zero-size, then it will not show expected layout.

The best way is providing non-zero layout (this is what IB does), but sometimes this is impossible.

If you cannot provide non-zero size, then I think you have to provide proper `- (void)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:(NSSize)oldSize` delegate method implementation to layout everything manually yourself. (this is my current best practice)