# NSSplitView initial divider position?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an NSSplitView that uses autolayout to position the two subviews inside of it.

Everything works great, but I want to set the initial position of the divider to a constant value (300 pixels) for aesthetic reasons.  I'm not using interface builder.

If I do `[_splitView setPosition:300 ofDividerAtIndex:0];`, I see no effect, same thing if I add a `[_splitView adjustSubviews]` call right after that.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you post more information about what constraints you have applied?    NSScrollView with autolayout constraints are a bit of a grey area (at least to me), I haven't manage to find any guidelines. What happens if you remove your constraints, does the divider move?

Comment: Isn't setting the position of the divider equivalent to setting the width of the view on the left side? Try setting the initial size of the left view to 300.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting Position of NSSplitView divider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995073/starting-position-of-nssplitview-divider)

Answer (score 5):

I met the same issue. It seems that `setPosition` has no effect if invoked right after you add subviews to the splitView.

I solve the problem by waiting a little while before invoking `setPosition`. Here is the sample code in swift:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

delay(0.05) {
    splitView.setPosition(300, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
}
```

Comment: You should invoke the `setPosition:ofDividerAtIndex:` function in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Such a strange solution

Answer (score 4):

I met the same issue, but I solved it calling setPosition from viewDidAppear. Hope this helps.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
  [self.splitView setPosition:300 ofDividerAtIndex:0];
}
```